# Sizing ImageViews Based off of Image Size

Tags: android, image, imageview

I know that the title makes it sound like it is a duplicate, but I think I have a very specific situation here that I can't solve from all of my searches.

First, I have images that are specifically sized based off of a specific monitor (Yes, monitor.  Not handheld device's screen).  The images are based off of these specific settings:

- 1600x900 20" monitor at 96ppi

Now, all of the images must be sized in millimeters (they are square images btw, so Height=Width).  Using these specific settings as a determining factor, 1mm = 3.78px.  So, my images are sized using this.  For example, for an image to appear as 65mm, I size the images to 246px.  I tested this in Photoshop using these settings, and measuring the image on the screen did in fact come out correct.

So now in my Android application, I load up these images into `ImageViews` to be displayed.  This is where I am stuck.  The device is an MDPI device.  If I load the images into the MDPI `drawables` folder, the images appear too large on the monitor.  Using my above example, I convert the `Drawable` to a `Bitmap` and dump the Height of the image to my log.  This is correct and shows 246px, but for some reason it is measuring well over 85mm instead of 65mm.

If I load all of my images into the HDPI (yes, I know it is an mdpi device so it will be sized by the Android OS), the height of the image (using my example) dumps as 164px and appears at roughly 50mm.  This is more explainable, but still I am still confused on how to get these images to appear as they did in Photoshop.

**So my question is**, what is the best way to programmatically size the `ImageView` to be the exact size of the image?  For my example, I need to find out why my 246px square image (at 96ppi) is not showing up as 65mm like it should.

Because these `ImageView`s are generated programmatically, I have tried the following two things:

1. Set the `ImageView` Height and Width (using `LayoutParams`) to the height of the image (246px).  I did this thinking `WRAP_CONTENT` was not acting as it should.
2. Used `ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER` to try and make sure the `ImageView` is sized exactly to the image.

Neither of these things seem to have effected the output.

**UPDATES:**

I have verified that my device is a MDPI device. This means that there is not DPI to PX conversion (or vice versa) necessary because of the 1:1 relationship.  Somewhere, the sizes are being increased and I cannot determine where.  As I indicated in the comments for the answer below, when I pull my Drawable and convert it to Bitmap, it pulls the EXACT pixel Height that I made it.  I am starting to figure out the percentage of size difference from what it should be (65mm vs 85mm) and it works out to be 23.529%.  I am scaling my bitmaps subtracting this value, but it ruins the quality of my image.

I am beginning to give up.

The device I am utilizing is an MK802III Rockchip Device ([Amazon Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00A0I4YJK))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate answering my own question, but I am just going to update everyone what I did. If someone comes up with a better solution, I am all ears. I had to force this along because I am on a tight deadline.

I created a dummy application that dumped boxes that I could measure.  Using these, I determined that 1 millimeter is 3 density pixels.  Let me repeat that, **1mm = 3dp**.

Using this value, I resized all of my images (utilizing a PHP script) to this constraint.  All of my images are appearing as normal.  195dp = 65mm, and it appears as such.

Like I said, any explanation as to why I had to do this and you get an upvote and answer.

Answer (score 2):

Android modifies all images for display with the following formula:

```
px = dp * (dpi / 160)
```

Where "dpi" is the screen density in dots-per-inch of a device's display.

Additionally, Android looks through a hierarchy of `drawable` folders when deciding which image to display. As we all know, an HDPI device will use an image from the `drawale-hdpi` folder while an MDPI device will display the same named image from the `drawable-mdpi` directory.

However, when an MDPI device cannot find an image in the `drawable-mdpi` directory, it will eventually choose from the `drawable-hdpi` folder, but it will down-scale the image for display on the MDPI screen.

This explains why your image appears smaller when you saved it in the `drawable-hdpi` folder.

But, it does not explain why the image appears too large when correctly placed in the `drawable-mdpi` folder.

It so happens that:

> 65mm ~= 85mm * (120 / 160)
>
> 50mm ~= 85mm * (120 / 240)

This is the scaling that I would expect for your images if your device were LDPI (120dpi) instead of MDPI (160dpi) as reported.

Comment: So if MDPI is 160dpi, should I up my images to in when it comes to ppi?  And I agree, I am baffled right now.  When using `getDisplayMetrics().density` it is pulling '1.0', which I looked up as MDPI.  What is really strange is that when I dump the image height from the Bitmap, it is pulling the exact px dimension I created the image for.  I wonder if it is taking that and converting it to DPI?

Comment: Also baffled. Your device is clearly MDPI and not behaving as I would expect. Do note that `Bitmap.getWidth()` does not necessarily report the same width that will be painted to the screen due to density scaling.

Comment: That's where I am hitting the wall.  `Bitmap.getHeight()/getWidth()` equal the EXACT number of pixels I generated the image as, but when I put it on the screen it does not appear as such.  When you covert this to DPI, because it is an MDPI device it has a 1:1 relationship so the 246px converts to 246dpi.  No matter what I do, though, the image is much larger than 65mm even though it is exact when I view it in Photoshop.  The Android device is changing it, I just can't find where.  I even hardcoded 246 to the `LayoutParams` and nothing changed.

Comment: I just remembered that images are treated differently if grabbed from resources vs if generated/resized as a `Bitmap` and then programmatically set to a `View`. I am helping you so hard because I banged my head about this same issue over an image I had to rotate. So, there is another way to determine the exact density of the screen but I had ignored that because the docs say only the quantized values are used. Let me look that up...

Comment: `xdpi` and `ydpi` are the exact screen density of the screen. Read them like this: `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().xdpi` and `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().ydpi`. See if you can use these values to unravel what is happening. I hopefully predict that these values will be approximately "122" on your device in order to account for the unexpected 85mm measurement you experienced.

Comment: Thanks for that! However when I pulled and dumped the values, they both were decimals that round down to 160, the MDPI density.